# System 1 and 2 thinking and unconcious

Tags: cognitive-psychology, unconscious, thought, analysis, intuition

Research [says](https://bigthink.com/errors-we-live-by/kahnemans-mind-clarifying-biases) there is system 1 and 2 thinking.

My question is how is system and and 2 thinking related to [unconcious mind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unconscious_mind)?
Can we say for example system 1 thinking is unconcious mind?

Answer (score 2):

[Peter Carruthers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_Carruthers_(philosopher))  argues [(2014)](http://faculty.philosophy.umd.edu/pcarruthers/The%20Fragmentation%20of%20Reasoning.pdf) that system 1 doesn't quite overlap with unconscious thinking:

> I shall argue that there is, indeed, a real, scientifically valid, distinction between a set of
>   intuitive, unconsciously operating reasoning systems, on the one hand, and a reflective system
>   whose operations are partly conscious, on the other. But I shall argue that this division fails to
>   line up with many of the other properties generally associated with Systems 1 and 2. In
>   particular, some intuitive systems can be slow, some can be controlled, and some can approach
>   the highest normative standards; so the moniker «quick and dirty» is certainly inappropriate
>   when applied to intuitive reasoning as such.

And [Jonathan Evans (2014)](http://cms.unige.ch/fapse/EmotionLab/pdf/Coppin%20(2014).%20BBS.pdf), a dual-process theorist but also strong critic of [UTT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unconscious_thought_theory), writes:

> It is true
>   that the distinction between conscious and nonconscious processing
>   has been emphasised by some social psychologists (e.g.,
>   Wilson 2002), but it is emphatically not the foundation for contemporary
>   dual-process theories of reasoning and decision
>   making. As a dual-process theorist, I have argued, in common
>   with others, that the conscious/unconscious decision cannot be
>   the basis for the dual-process distinction because it is too vague
>   and fails to define the key central properties of dual processing
>   (Evans & Stanovich 2013). I should also point out that in spite
>   of defending the validity of much of the research that N&S criticise
>   here, I have in common with them critiqued unconscious
>   thinking theory and other strong assertions of the powers of intuition
>   (see Evans 2010, Ch. 4). This is because dual-process theory
>   confines powers of reflective reasoning – and with it the ability to
>   deal with novel and difficult problems – to Type 2 processing.
>   The case for dual process is in fact based not on the conscious/
>   unconscious distinction but on the claim that there are two forms
>   of cognitive processing which have distinctive properties and
>   which reflect the operation of distinct cognitive and neural
>   systems. Most of these properties are merely typical correlates,
>   and few are defining features (Evans & Stanovich 2013). I agree
>   with Stanovich that Type 2 processing is distinguished both by
>   its cognitive resources (central working memory, correlation
>   with measures of cognitive capacity) and by its ability to engage
>   in cognitive decoupling and hypothetical thinking. The apparent
>   link of dual-process theory with consciousness comes only from
>   the fact that some of the items attended in working memory are
>   available to verbal report. But using broader definitions of consciousness,
>   I have argued in detail that both Type 1 and Type 2
>   thinking have aspects that are conscious as well as unconscious
>   (Evans 2010, Ch. 7).
>   In conclusion, not only do I reject the authors’ presumption of
>   conscious decision making, which I believe to be shakily founded
>   on folk psychology, but I also contest their implication that the
>   conscious/unconscious distinction is the basis for contemporary
>   theories of dual processing in higher cognition.

Answer (score 1):

Another classic distinction was given by Bargh in 1997 that helps show muddling (lack of clear overlap) between the dual-systems concept and how the unconscious is defined by psychologists:

> Unconscious cognition is more likely to be one or more: outside awareness, not intended, relatively fast, and difficult to control.
>
> http://psycnet.apa.org/record/1994-97751-001